Quarkus REST Client: How to serialize a query parameter with custom date formatter
I have a REST API to call that expects dates in the format yyyyMMdd
My REST Client code looks like this
@GET
@Path("/atl/")
RestResponse<AtlResponse> getAtlResponse(
    @QueryParam("from") LocalDate from
);

and the query parameter gets formatted like this:

from=2021-07-03

I tried
@GET
@Path("/atl/")
RestResponse<AtlResponse> getAtlResponse(
    @QueryParam("from") @DateFormat(pattern="yyyyMMdd") LocalDate from
);

but I have the same result.
Of course I could replace with a String and format the date before calling this API but that would be a shame :)
Thanks !

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Can you try it with:
@QueryParam("from") 
@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat(shape = STRING, pattern = "yyyyMMdd") 
LocalDate from


That doesn't work. I still get from=2021-05-06
